# Clone all BitBucket Repositories From a Project using jq

Tags: git, jq, bitbucket-api

I am trying to clone all repositories in my team's project in BitBucket.

I want to extract the url and the name from the JSON returned from the REST call and use those values to clone

Below is what I have

```
curl -s http://bitbucketlocalserver:7990/rest/api/1.0/projects/PROJECT_NAME/repos?per_page=20 ^
 -u user:pass | H:\Downloads\Win64\jq-win64.exe -r ".values[] | .links.clone[] | select(.name==\"http\") | .href" ^
  H:\Utilities\Git\usr\bin\xargs.exe -L1 git clone  -b release/development
```

This works for the url, but what I want to do is also change the name of the directory to the Name attribute, e.g. GitRepository1, GitRepository2 etc., instead of gitrepo1, gitrepo2 that is used automatically when that parameter is not passed

So, something similar to

```
curl -s http://bitbucketlocalserver:7990/rest/api/1.0/projects/PROJECT_NAME/repos?per_page=20 ^
 -u user:pass | H:\Downloads\Win64\jq-win64.exe -r ".values[] | .links.clone[] | select(.name==\"http\") | .href" ^
  H:\Utilities\Git\usr\bin\xargs.exe -L1 git clone  -b release/development git_url dir_name
```

I need help with the jq command to select the two attributes and pass to the xargs command

And this is the json structure

```
{
  "size": 25,
  "limit": 25,
  "isLastPage": false,
  "values": [
    {
      "slug": "gitrepo1",
      "id": 2216,
      "name": "GitRepository1",
      "scmId": "git",
      "state": "AVAILABLE",
      "statusMessage": "Available",
      "forkable": true,
      "project": {
        "key": "PROJECT_NAME",
        "id": 1369,
        "name": "PROJECT_NAME",
        "description": "ABC Team",
        "public": false,
        "type": "NORMAL",
        "links": {
          "self": [
            {
              "href": "http://bitbucketlocalserver:7990/projects/PROJECT_NAME"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "public": false,
      "links": {
        "clone": [
          {
            "href": "ssh://git@bitbucketlocalserver:7999/PROJECT_NAME/gitrepo1.git",
            "name": "ssh"
          },
          {
            "href": "http://bitbucketlocalserver:7990/scm/PROJECT_NAME/gitrepo1.git",
            "name": "http"
          }
        ],
        "self": [
          {
            "href": "http://bitbucketlocalserver:7990/projects/PROJECT_NAME/repos/gitrepo1/browse"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "slug": "gitrepo2",
      "id": 2214,
      "name": "GitRepository2",
      "scmId": "git",
      "state": "AVAILABLE",
      "statusMessage": "Available",
      "forkable": true,
      "project": {
        "key": "PROJECT_NAME",
        "id": 1369,
        "name": "PROJECT_NAME",
        "description": "ABC Team",
        "public": false,
        "type": "NORMAL",
        "links": {
          "self": [
            {
              "href": "http://bitbucketlocalserver:7990/projects/PROJECT_NAME"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "public": false,
      "links": {
        "clone": [
          {
            "href": "ssh://git@bitbucketlocalserver:7999/PROJECT_NAME/gitrepo2.git",
            "name": "ssh"
          },
          {
            "href": "http://bitbucketlocalserver:7990/scm/PROJECT_NAME/gitrepo2.git",
            "name": "http"
          }
        ],
        "self": [
          {
            "href": "http://bitbucketlocalserver:7990/projects/PROJECT_NAME/repos/gitrepo2/browse"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "start": 0,
  "nextPageStart": 25
}
```

Is it possible?  How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command below gives the output needed

```
curl -s http://bitbucketlocalserver:7990/rest/api/1.0/projects/PROJECT_NAME/repos?limit=100 ^
-u user:pass | H:\Downloads\Win64\jq-win64.exe -r "[.values[] | ((.links.clone[] | select(.name==\"http\") |  .href)  + \" \" +  .name)]"
```

The output from this command is

```
[
   "http://bitbucketlocalserver:7990/scm/PROJECT_NAME/gitrepo1.git GitRepository1",
   "http://bitbucketlocalserver:7990/scm/PROJECT_NAME/gitrepo1.git GitRepository2"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to execute as many git commands as there are relevant items in the stream `.values[].links.clones[]`, the key to simplicity here is to use jq to construct them.  The following jq filter will do the job:

```
 .values[]
 | .name as $name
 | .links.clone[] | select(.name=="http") 
 | "git clone -b release/development \"\(.href)\" \($name)"
```

(To avoid hassles with the quotation marks when using Windows, you might find it simplest to put the filter in a file.)

Comment: Thanks.  Actually, that is what I am trying - to get the jq construct working.  I tried the above but get errors.  Need some help in understanding how to use jq correctly.   Appreciate any help ...
 H:\Downloads\Win64\jq-win64.exe -r ".values[] | .name as $name | .links.clone[] | select(.name==\"http\")"   | "git clone -b release/development \"\(.href)\" \($name)"
'"git clone -b release/development \"\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: As implied in the parenthetical remark, I'd suggest using jq's -f command-line option.