# Need help consolidating three sed calls into one

Tags: bash, sed, sh

I have a variable called TR_VERSION that is a JSON list of version numbers that looks something like this:

```
[
    "1.0.1",
    "1.0.2",
    "1.0.3"
]
```

I would like to strip all of the JSON specific characters - `[`, `"`, `,` and `]`. The following code works but it would be great to consolidate to one sed call instead of three.

```
TR_VERSION=$(echo $VERSION \
| sed 's|[",]||g' \
| sed 's/\[//' \
| sed 's/\]//')
```

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: So - in the end, you will use proper JSON tools to process JSON objects, which is the right thing to do. Back to your regexp though - the bottom line (as illustrated by Viktor's answer) is that you **can** include all characters in a character set. Those (the very small number) that have special meaning in a character set can still be included - they just must be in positions where their "special meaning" would make no sense. For example: closing bracket right after the opening one (can only mean literal `]`,  it makes no sense as metacharacter there), or dash `-` right at the end of the class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQ - How to define filter to remove brackets, quotes and commas from output array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58566524/jq-how-to-define-filter-to-remove-brackets-quotes-and-commas-from-output-arra)

Answer (score 2):

Never ever use [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) to parse [json](/questions/tagged/json).

This is the way to go:

```
$ jq -r '.[]' < file.json
```

### Output as expected

```
1.0.1
1.0.2
1.0.3
```

Comment: Ah very nice use of -r option, this is making me reconsider how I'm currently parsing JSON with `jq`, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove all `"`, `,`, `[` and `]` chars you may use

```
TR_VERSION=$(echo "$VERSION" | sed 's/[][",]//g')
```

Or,

```
TR_VERSION=$(sed 's/[][",]//g' <<< "$VERSION")
```

The `[][",]` pattern matches `]`, `[`, `"` or `,` chars.

Comment: @GillesQuenot Of course not. I just suggested a way to literally **remove all `"`, `,`, `[` and `]`**, not to parse any JSON. See the top of the answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks your solution works perfectly for my use case, @GillesQuenot I'm parsing with `jq` in another part of the program that's less relevant to the question

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to avoid a JSON parer, there is still no need to use `sed`. You could also do it by

```
 TR_VERSION=$(tr -d '[]",' <<<$VERSION)
```

which, IMHO, is slightly better readable than the *sed*  counterpart.